# Draw random numbers from Boost binomial distribution

Tags: c++, random, boost, binomial-cdf

Here is an example to draw random numbers from a binomial distribution with `std::binomial_distribution`

```
#include <random>
int main ()
{
   std::mt19937 eng(14);
   std::binomial_distribution<size_t> dist(28,0.2);
   size_t randomNumber = dist(eng);

   return 0;
}
```

I am failing to find a similar example for boost. I went through [this documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/math/example/binomial_coinflip_example.cpp), which explains how to compute PDF, CDF and others from a `boost::math::binomial` object but they are not talking about sampling a random number.

Should I write a binary search myself based on the CDF that  `boost::math::binomial` will compute for me or can boost directly return random numbers?

Comment: Maybe you should start searching from here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html or https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/random/binomial_distribution.html

Comment: Thank you that link solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) from @Bob__, here is a simple working example

```
#include <random>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

int main ()
{
   std::mt19937 eng;
   boost::random::binomial_distribution<int> dist(28,0.2);
   int randomNumber = dist(eng);

   return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it would not compile with `size_t`, so I used `int` (see @Bob__'s comment below for more information).

Comment: Well, somewhere, in the log [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EGYIp4lim1z28yYC), there's an *"error: call of overloaded 'abs(long unsigned int)' is ambiguous"*, while https://ideone.com/Td4Rvl doesn't complain...